# A record pointed to an external ip + virtualhosts

Tags: dns, apache-http-server

Good morning, I have 2 servers (#1 and #2)
My domain name is pointed to #1 and there in the DNS zone I pointed the "A record" to #2 IP address, (with this setup I can have mails on #1 and website on #2).
I know it's easier to make it the other way around but #2 is 100% configured by hand (#1 has cpanel) and I want to avoid potential DNS and mail issues.

The #2 is running Apache2 and I have virtual hosts configured there, however my domain name loads /var/www content (apache default) and not /home/myuser/www/ which is the patch specified as DocumentRoot.
I know virtual hosts are properly configured because previously I had the domain name pointed to #2 and they worked well.

What I am missing here guys?

apache2.conf: http://pastebin.com/52WB7LUw

Comment: Can you share your apache config? Its difficult to say what's wrong without it

Comment: I just added virtual host config

Comment: When you say your domain name points to #1, do you have an [A record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#A) that points to the IP address of #1, so that external systems looking up your domain name, e.g., example.com, are pointed to the IP address of #1? It is somewhat confusing when you state you are using an A record to point to #2 immediately after saying your domain name resolves to #1. Do you have something like www.example.com pointing to #2 by the other entry in your zone file? Why didn't you use an [Mx record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) for email?

Comment: @moonpoint hi, yes, domain resolves to #1 and there the A record points to #2 ip address, I do it that way because as I said, #1 has a reliable DNS configuration and #2 doesn't. This is not a situation where I can simply modify the MX record, note what I want to "forward" is website not emails.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is how it resolves to #1, if the A record in the zone file for the domain has the IP address for #2. If I performed an [nslookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup). e.g., `nslookup example.com`, would I get the IP address of #1 or #2? Are you stating #1 is a DNS server that is authoritative for your domain? Is the problem you are having now that people can reach your site on #2, but are getting the wrong content?

Comment: nslookup returns #2 ip, as stated previously the problem is apache loads default content and not the domain specific one, or in other words: virtual hosts aren't working.

Comment: Your virtualhost section looks correct; did you restart Apache after updating the httpd.conf file?

Comment: I did, I think I will perform a fresh system install and see what happens, thanks for the help.